# How to get the confusion matrix multi classes images Keras R

Tags: r, keras, confusion-matrix

I have trained my model(4 classes) using keras R and now I want to evaluate the model on my test set of images.

I cannot find the way to get the confusion matrix for my 4 classes of images in R. Is there a way to create confusion matrix for all my classes?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
class_names = c(1,2,3,4)
pool_size <- 2

  model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 4,input_shape = c(64, 64, 3)) %>%  
  layer_activation(activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 8, kernel_size = kernel_size) %>%
  layer_activation(activation = 'relu') %>%  
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 4, activation = "softmax")

train_datagen = image_data_generator(
  rescale = 1/255,
  rotation_range = 40,
  width_shift_range = 0.2,
  height_shift_range = 0.2,
  shear_range = 0.2,
  zoom_range = 0.2,
  horizontal_flip = TRUE,
  fill_mode = "nearest"
)

test_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)  

train_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  train_dir,                    
  target_size = c(64, 64),  
  batch_size = 16,
  class_mode = "categorical"       
)
validation_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  validation_dir,
  test_datagen,
  target_size = c(64, 64),
  batch_size = 16,
  class_mode = "categorical"
)
model %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 1e-4),
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)
history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch = 100,
  verbose = 1,
  epochs = 100,
  validation_data = validation_generator,
  validation_steps = 50
)
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/confusion-matrix-calculation-r

Comment: Do you mean after evaluation=     test_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
    test_dir,...), then :    evaluation %>% evaluate_generator(test_generator),   write:   confusionmatrix(evaluation ,test_dir) ?